# Using wimax internet service directly through in home wifi router all devices connect by wifi extending by service wireless bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge, repeater

My internet service connects directly to my in home router. From a poe modem everything I have connects wireless.

To extend my internet service 1/3 mile with wifi access at the other end without adding another router, what configuration should I use with wireless bridge that has 4 working modes: bridge, ap,  repeater,  router.

[image: Comfastcf-e314n]